# Mongoose Post Hook for create() rather than update()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but everything I can find for having a post hook for `create()` on a mongoose model brings up the `update()` method instead. Are `create()` and `update()` the same?

What I want to do is when a `User` document is created, send a welcome email, without having to manually call the method on every route/controller that creates a user.

I understand a little about pre- and post- hooks, and I have a pre-remove hook:

```js
userSchema.pre('remove', async function() {
    for (let response of this.responses) {
        Response.findByIdAndRemove(response);
    };
});
```

But I can't find anything within mongoose docs for a post-hook for `create()`.

If `create()` and `update()` are the same, what stops this welcome email from being sent any time the user's information is changed? I only want this to send once, at the very beginning.

Let me know if I'm clear as mud

Comment: For future reference, if yuo look at their docs under `pre`  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre you will notice they actually show an example of detecting create via the date fields created the by the timestamp option, while not a direct method of asking if created it does work for most models for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer, finally, in the Mongoose docs in a roundabout way through a github feature request: `schema.queue`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-queue

So I define the `method`(s) that I want to execute at the time the document is instantiated, then just use the `schema.queue` command like so:

`schema.queue('methodName',[args]);`

For the time being, I left the `args` array empty because they're only operating on themselves, so no other information needs to go in.

The docs don't say it specifically, but I would assume since declaring methods looks to be the same as declaring any function, the `queue` method can be called before or after declaring the method it calls, but I played it safe and put it after.

Man, this is exciting.